# Are tag edits of less than 6 characters supposed to be allowed

Tags: bug, tags

Now that the retag feture has been merged with the edit feature tag edits also have to be over 6 characters? A question can legitimately have only one character in tags? Is this an intended side effect of the change? For [How to check whether STL iterator points at anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824157/how-to-check-whether-stl-iterator-points-at-anything) if I click the edit link, then remove [valid](/questions/tagged/valid) I get the error edits must be at least 6 charicters. My browser is Safari on iOS 6.0.

Comment: "Are tag edits of less than 6 characters allowed" : Have you tried ?

Comment: Are you saying that tag edits now come with the same character limit as well?

Comment: I've reproduced this behaviour on the question mentioned.

Comment: can you still reproduce the same behavior?

Comment: no i can not, probably fixed.

Comment: @m0sa [yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303041/cannot-suggest-retag-only-edit-because-of-subjective-title-warning). Can you please remove the red tag here?

Comment: @m0sa - I had the same problem on this question: [Does the big bang model describe a first momment in time for the entire universe or just the observable universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408834/does-the-big-bang-model-describe-a-first-momment-in-time-for-the-entire-universe) a moment ago. --- First I wanted to add **only** the tag "big-bang", six characters but not accepted. Next I tried a C/R, no help. Then I tried splitting a sentence, fail. Finally I corrected the grammar minutely. Success.

Comment: There must have been something odd about that question in its initial state, @Rob - a tag-only edit should have gone through. Nothing's jumping out at me though, and I haven't been able to reproduce the problem. Ping me if you see this again, ideally *without* working around the problem.

Comment: @Shog9 - I will. I've ⭐'d the question (so I might find it easier, plus I'll remember it). Checking the 'Edit History'. it appears that the "status-completed" tag was given on "Jan 30 '14" - that's before I joined. I've seen this problem at least a 1/2 dozen times on various SE sites since I've been here. You probably have 'hammer access' and the system doesn't mess with you. I had to go through contortions to avoid changing the question, and force-feed it the sorely missing tag. I'll ping you here, probably within a week (I'll ***hunt*** for legitimately missing tags from now on).

Comment: @Shog9 As requested in the comment above, here is a ping about when a tag only edit fails: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6/2-stage-stochastic-programming-to-approximate-many-stage-problems#comment20_6 - and the tag was much greater than 6 characters, so it's a little different than 'under 6 char tags' problem.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they should be.  Retagging doesn't character count.  If not it's a bug and report as such, and perhaps the supporting text should be clearer.

Comment: Seems to be localised to a single question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824157/how-to-check-whether-stl-iterator-points-at-anything so quite strange

Comment: @user1937198 post information on what you tried on that question, what happened, and retag this question as bug, if you are in fact experiencing this behavior.