# Cannot suggest retag-only edit because "edits must be at least 6 characters"

Tags: bug, tags, suggested-edits

I was trying to suggest a retag of [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/74470/36324) on Seasoned Advice, but the system won't let me; I get the familiar message

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

In general, that's not true for retagging; if you don't change the question body *at all*, it should work. I suspect the logic checking the edit is thrown off guard because of the title warning:

> The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed

---

[image]

I found [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180003/295232), but I cannot find any evidence (in SEDE) for invisible characters being present in the question's source. Also, that's supposed to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Do you know that it is due to the tag notice? It seems that this may not actually be possible (submitting tag-only edit suggestions).

Comment: @Catija It's supposed to be possible. On a *small* number of questions, you get an error message saying that "edits must have at least 6 characters", but that's a bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There was a single zero-width space at the end of the post body. These are stripped on submission now... Unfortunately, that's done *before* the system compares the revisions to see what has changed. So it saw the tag edits *and* a one-character body edit.

The subjective title warning is entirely incidental. As usual, the fault lies with Unicode.

This generally happens when characters are stripped out from the body currently, but weren't stripped out in the prior revision of the post. The system sees the stripping as a body edit and thus prevents you from submitting the edit since the body edit was under 6 characters.

Comment: So that's one possible cause of my getting that message even when I make no edits to the body? What are the general causes of this happening?

Comment: General cause is stuff the system strips from the post *prior to* checking against the last revision, @Ano. In cases where these manage to sneak into the post body anyway, they'll trigger this the next time someone tries to edit.

Comment: So this situation occurs if a post was made before the stripping algorithm was changed? Is that why I see [the error message I mention in this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303041/cannot-suggest-retag-only-edit-because-of-subjective-title-warning#comment997009_303041) more often on old posts?

Comment: Yep, that's the most common cause, @Ano. Can also happen if the check is skipped on edits, if the check is done *before* stripping but applied against revisions where the stripping has already happened, etc.

Comment: [Here](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3734/8282) is another case where it looks like this bug happens. If you have a minute or two, I think the user there will appreciate a reply.

Comment: @Shog You asked me to [remind you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179595/are-tag-edits-of-less-than-6-characters-supposed-to-be-allowed#comment1015027_179595) if I ever saw/heard of this problem.

Comment: Where'd you run into it again, @Rob?

Comment: @Shog9 - Here, and there. I usually don't edit tags but I recall editing a short tag (several months ago) without other edits and it was accepted; so I thought it was fixed. Now I see this report here, it's the first reoccurrence since that time - so I'm linking the two, letting you know. Maybe it occurs rarely but remains an unfixed bug.