# Cannot edit, hit 6-character limit even though I did not touch post body at all

Tags: bug, edits

I tried to edit [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/revisions/58868/1) to add a relevant tag (and nothing more), but the interface claimed that I must make an edit of more than six characters.

Previously the interface has accepted tag-only and title-only edits.

I have seen this before on some other posts.

My best guess is that there was an empty line at the start of the post which the interface removed and thought that it was part of my edit.

Comment: @Glorfindel I see a [status-completed] on that but the bug has not been fixed, has it? Is closing this report as a duplicate to a five-year-old question the right method to get it fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure. I asked a [similar question before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303041/295232) which I *thought* was closed as a duplicate as well, but it turns out it isn't. So it's a known problem but apparently it doesn't have too much priority.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog The response to that question states that the auto-cleanup rules changed between the making of the post and the edit; and indeed, the post in question was made in 2016 and the edit attempted in 2018. In my case, the edit was attempted on the same day as the post was made.